# MongoDB $lookup pipeline match by _id not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm trying to do a `$lookup` in a collection and add some data to my documents. The problem is that when i try matching my `$lookup` pipeline by `_id` it returns an empty array. Here is my code:

```
Schedule.aggregate([{ // My Schedule schema
  $match: {
    store: req.query.store,
    "customer.id": req.query.user
  }
},
{
  $skip: +req.query.skip
}, {
  $limit: +req.query.limit
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: Employee.collection.name, // "employee" schema,
    let: {
      id: "$employee.id" // employee _id from the "schedule" collection match above
    },
    pipeline: [{
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            "_id": "$$id" // here i try to match by _id
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $project: { // the only fields i need
          "_id": 1,
          "avatar": 1,
          "name": 1
        }
      }
    ],
    as: "employees" // employees is returned as []
  }
}
]).exec((err, resolve) => {
  if (err) console.log('error', err);
  res.json(resolve);
});
```

If it helps here's both my collections used in this aggregation:

Schedule schema:

```
const ScheduleSchema = new Schema({
  store: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  customer: {
    id: {
      type: String
    },
    name: {
      type: String
    },
    avatar: String,
    phone: {
      type: String
    },
    email: { type: String },
    doc: {
      type: String
    },
  },
  employee: {
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    avatar: String,
  },
  service: {
    id: {
      type: String
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    filters: [String]
  },
  info: {
    channel: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: 'app'
    },
    id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String
  },
  scheduleDate: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  scheduleStart: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  scheduleEnd: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  value: {
    type: Number
  },
  comissionType: {
    type: String,
    default: '$'
  },
  comissionValue: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  status: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  observation: String,
  paymentMethod: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  paymentValue: String,
  paymentChange: String,
  color: String
}, {
    timestamps: {
      createdAt: 'created',
      updatedAt: 'updated'
    }
  });
```

Employee Schema:

```
const EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  a_to_z: String, // nome normalizado, só minusculas e sem espaços
  description: String,
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  avatar: String,
  phone: {
    type: String
  },
  storeOwner: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  permissions: [
    {
      route: String,
      hasPermission: Boolean
    }
  ],
  scheduleAutomatic: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: false
  },
  password: {
    passwordHash: String,
    salt: String
  },
  active: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
  storeKey: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  notification_token: String,
  notification_tokens: {
    type: [String],
    default: []
  },
  workingHours: [{
    weekDay: {
      type: Number,
    },
    doesWork: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
    startHour: String,
    endHour: String,
    lunchStart: String,
    lunchEnd: String
  }],
  config: {
    available_days: {
      type: Number,
      default: 365
    },
    in_advance_schedule: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    in_advance_interval: {
      type: String,
      default: 'minute'
    }
  }
}, {
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: 'created',
    updatedAt: 'updated'
  } 
});
```

### EDIT

The result i'm trying to achieve is this:
[image: Result example]

The `employees` property is the one i'm trying to use `$lookup` to get, it'll have the same data as the `employee` property, in the end it'll be and array of objects with just one object inside.

Some sample docs:

Schedule:

```
color: "lavander",
created: "2018-07-31T18:50:53.423Z",
customer: {id: "5b60a67206e8a65f48a15f13", name: "Gabriel Barreto", phone: "11995274098", cpf: "40735255814"},
employee: {id: "5b2952c68424872fccece7f5", name: "Gabriel Barreto", avatar: null},
observation: "teste",
scheduleDate: "2018-08-01",
scheduleEnd: "2018-08-01 08:30",
scheduleStart: "2018-08-01 08:00",
service: {filters: Array(3), id: "5b606e8cc59e82354cc931e2", name: "Corte Masc"},
status: 1,
store: "5b16cceb56a44e2f6cd0324b",
updated: "2018-11-27T13:27:40.310Z",
value: 25,
__v: 0,
_id: "5b60af8de558661acc5d70b9"
```

Employee:

```
a_to_z: "gabrielbarreto",
active: true,
avatar: "gabriel_barreto_h7qvcn.jpg",
config: {available_days: 180, in_advance_schedule: 10, in_advance_interval: "hour"},
created: "2018-06-19T19:00:22.315Z",
currency: "BRL",
description: "Novo perfil",
email: "gabriel.barreto@wabiz.com.br",
lang: "pt-BR",
name: "Gabriel Barreto",
notification_token: "2d768670-6011-4873-846d-39580b0d82d0",
notification_tokens: ["53049a82-53dc-4bc3-9646-7a4bee1f367b"],
password: null,
permissions: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}],
phone: "11995274098",
scheduleAutomatic: false,
storeKey: "5b16cceb56a44e2f6cd0324b",
storeOwner: true,
token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImdhYnJpZWwuYmFycmV0b0B3YWJpei5jb20uYnIiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTA2NzEwNDQsImV4cCI6MTU1MzI2MzA0NH0.0Odizd8pS4WPGSqm_2_XrTw1YE8NMOOXnHIrG-WVxGo",
updated: "2019-02-20T13:34:20.619Z",
workingHours: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}],
__v: 0,
_id: "5b2952c68424872fccece7f5"
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: One of off-topic reasons reads "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include ...  the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."  Your question lacks very essential part - example of documents that you think should be included in the array. Please add 1 document from the schedule collection and the matching one from the employee collection.

Comment: You probably need to use aggregation operator inside the `$expr` . `{
        $match: {
          $expr: {
           $eq: [ "$_id","$$id"]
          }
        }
      }`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet tried what you said and still empty results. If i remove the `$eq` and leave just `"_id": "$$id"` i get all my documents in `Employee` collection, maybe my `$employee.id` is invalid or i'm not reaching this value in my first `match` expressions

Comment: @GabrielBarreto Hi, do you figure out the problem ?

Comment: I think you have missed a `$` sign just before `_id`: `$match: { $expr: { "$_id": "$$id" } }`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was in trouble too while using $lookup with mongoose to trying to match _id as my collection store the reference as a String and not an ObjectId

Model A: {_id: ObjectId("xxx"), b_id: "eeeee"}

Model B: {_id: ObjectId("eeeee")}

```
MyCollectionA.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup: {
        from: "collectionb",
        let: {id: "$b_id"},
        pipeline: [{$match: {$expr: {$eq: ["$_id", "$$id"]}}}],
        as: b
      }
])
```

In this example b is never filled as $$id is not considered as an ObjectId

Just add a project to transform $$id in an objectId and its working

```
MyCollectionA.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup: {
        from: "collectionb",
        let: {id: "$b_id"},
        pipeline: [
           {$project: {_id: 1, bid: {"$toObjectId": "$$id"}}},
           {$match: {$expr: {$eq: ["$_id", "$bid"]}}}
        ],
        as: b
      }
])
```

Or with foreignField, localField:

```
MyCollectionA.aggregate([
   {
      $project:{
        _id: 1,
        b_id: {"$toObjectId": "$b_id"}
      }
   },
   {
      $lookup: {
        from: "collectionb",
        localField: "b_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: b
      }
])
```

Comment: wow, solution totally worked for me. Thanks Daphoque and sorry for the delay on the response.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
MyCollectionA.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup: {
        from: "collectionb",
        let: {id: "$b_id"},
        pipeline: [
           {$match: {$expr: {$eq: ["$_id", {"$toObjectId": "$$id"}]}}}
        ],
        as: b
      }
])
```