# Filter the collection in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have three collections in my MongoDB project. one collection includes users, another one for user-specific accounts, and the last one is some Campaigns.

I wanted to get the Campaigns based on user-specific platforms.

The campaign documents look as below.

```
[{
id: "401",
maxfollowers: "645963",
minfollowers: "2665",
name: "test 12",
platform: "Youtube",
status: "Active",
userId: "123"
},
{
id: "402",
maxfollowers: "6202",
minfollowers: "500",
name: "test 123",
platform: "Toktok",
status: "Active",
userId: "123"
}]
```

The account documents look as below.

```
[{
id: "501",
followers: "6000",
platform: "Youtube",
userId: "123"
},
{
id: "502",
followers: "500",
platform: "Toktok",
userId: "123"
}]
```

here the user with Id = 123, has two accounts. based on the user accounts platform and followers, I wanted to write a query to get the campaigns list.

below is the code that I have tried.

```
Account.find({userId})
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result)
                const platforms = [];
                result.forEach(item => {
                  // frame the query here.
                });
                Advertisement.find(search)
                    .then(response => {
                        res.status(200).json({
                            data: response
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        errorHandler(res, err);
                    });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                errorHandler(res, err);
            });
```

I am using NodeJs, express js and mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use aggregate with $lookup in order to join collection, see [MongoDB $lookup pipeline match by _id not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886134/mongodb-lookup-pipeline-match-by-id-not-working/63917197#63917197)